# Bringing up an extJs application for testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, extjs, siesta

Nothing is rendered on DomPanel while testing a view. I have used Ext.create() to get an instance of the view.
I have tried testing examples of Siesta which are rendered properly. But it fails for pages of our application.

Please suggest the possible solutions.

Comment: Whats the error you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error but nothing is rendered on DomPanel and so I am not able to use features like click.